# how to design Hospital RDBMS in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have use MySQL and database design like this.

[image: hospital rdbms design]

This database is part design for hospital.
In patient table have more than 1.500.000 record of patient.
In clinic table have 15 record.
In doctor table have 25 record.
In diagnose table have more than 500 record.
In out_condition table have 10 record.

And all table to be relate in table transaction_current. 
After finish, the transaction moved to history table.

Is this a bad design  ? because in query select, need more than a minute for getting one patient in browse mode.
If this is the best relation design, how should i use select query for transaction table with all relation table reference included.

Thanks to you for help.

edited :
"Sorry... where is my image design? is only my borwser does?..."

this is sample select query

```
select  transaction_current.registration_number, 
        transaction_current.Date_registration, 
        patient.mr_code, 
        patient.patient_name,
        clinic.Poly_clinic_name, 
        doctor.doctor_name, 
        diagnose.diagnose_name,
        out_condition.OC_name
from transaction_current,patient, clinic, doctor, diagnose, out_condition
where   transaction_current.patient_code=patient.MR_code and 
        transaction_current.clinic_code=clinic.clinic_code and 
        transaction_current.doctor_code=doctor.doctor_code and 
        transaction_current.diagnose_code=diagnose.doagnose_code and 
        transaction_current.OC_code=Out_Condition.OC_code
        and patient.patient_name = 'xxx%'
```

answered :
after careful answer from mr. rj45, is sometimes not recommended any normalization. especially for historical data. if there is a change in the reference table, the history data will also be changed.
case like this ...
if the code change doctors, or deleted, then the record will follow the change history. when it is not in the will. its extreme, the data history will not come out, because the relationship code no matches.
Thank you so much @rj45

Comment: try to ask in dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: index in all p_key, but not in f_key

Comment: What do mean by "one patient in browse mode"? just to search or else ? and please give your sample select query too

Comment: thanks for Shivan. i'll try in that site.

Comment: @rj45 yes. for searching and get patient information in billing transaction.

Comment: Do you have indexes in every column used as a foreign key (and especially the `patient_code`? What are the datatypes of these columns? Do you have an index on `patient_name`?

Comment: I think it would be better if you provided the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output so we know the exact structure of the tables (engine, datatypes, PKs, FKs, etc). And perhaps the `EXPLAIN` output of your query.

Comment: @ypercube,i 'am sorry, that is will make confuse, because in my real design i use a symbolic table name and column name, such as H1 for table patient, H2 for table doctor and any else.. (it make more simple query code :) ). thank you response.

Comment: Simpler code? Or harder to read?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16181/discussion-between-ypercube-and-candra-purnama)

Comment: @ypercube yes.. harder, without table documentary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to apply some optimization steps to your query.

eg : 
 - Use operator EXISTS, IN and table joins appropriately in your query

Better to avoid too much comparison in where clause. I believe it is the place where you have the lag. You may compare the fields which have build index. So it will much faster on the query.

P.S. : Even though the normalization is there some times it is better to stick with less normalized form(by experiences ;))

Comment: hm... you mean in the transaction not save "code" as 'f_key'? so in transaction have like this... doctor_name, clinic_name, ...etc? thanks for you answer. referensce link, please.. to re design my RDBMS

Comment: Glad to help you  Candra Purnama. I sow your edit and you got the poin. Furthermore there are more optimizing techniques. Google for "sql query optimization" you'll find more useful tips. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your table design seems fine. It is normalized and I wouldn't expect any performance issues coming from the design. Further details as the engine used (InnoDB?), the specific tables' definitions and the existing indices would help others giving more advice.

Your query seems to be joining 4 rather small tables and two larger one (`patient`and `transaction_current`). So, if you have defined the foreign keys as your image shows and they are indexed (and both referencing and referenced columns of same datatype), this query should be quite fast.

The most probable bottleneck would be if there is no index on `patient_name`. This would require a table scan of the `patient` table.

Comment: yes. InnoDB is used in all my table. all primary_key(p_key) is indices, but not all f_key. and as u wrote, patient.patient_name, does't indexed. i have try to indexing this patient_name, and make reduce view second, but still limit a minute. I think with "patient.patient_name" as "key_word search", should be indexed. that is right? if i change the clause in WHERE will give good result? ex; from "transaction_current.clinic_code=clinic.clinic_code" to "clinic.clinic_code=transaction_current.clinic_code". thank's for your explanation.

Comment: Do you have Foreign Keys defined in the `CREATE TABLE` statements or not?

Comment: Sorry, i am late. Not all time online. In transaction_current with f_key is foreign key.

Comment: Another thing is the `patient.patient_name = 'xxx%'`. Did you mean to write `patient.patient_name LIKE 'xxx%'` ?